# Difference between <Location> and <Directory> Apache directives

Tags: apache-2.2, directory, httpd.conf

I have Zend Server installed and noticed something like the following was added to my httpd.conf file:

```
<Location /ZendServer>
 Order Allow,Deny
 Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Location>

Alias /ZendServer "C:\Program Files\Zend\ZendServer\GUI\html"

<Directory "C:\Program Files\Zend\ZendServer\GUI\html">
 AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

But I can't seem to understand the difference between **Location** and **Directory**. I changed to something like the following, which makes more sense to me, and it still works:

```
<Location /ZendServer>
 AllowOverride All
 Order Allow,Deny
 Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Location>

Alias /ZendServer "C:\Program Files\Zend\ZendServer\GUI\html"
```

Can I keep my changes or should I put it back the way it was?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`Directory` directive works only for filesystem objects (e.g. /var/www/mypage, C:\www\mypage), while `Location` directive works only for URLs (the part after your site domain name, e.g. www.mypage.com/mylocation).

The usage is straightforward - you would use `Location` if you need to fine tune access rights by an URL, and you would use `Directory` if you need to control access rights to a directory (and its subdirectories) in the filesystem.

Comment: I'm still confused... Why did Zend used both then? Can I keep my changes or is something wrong with that?

Comment: No, your configuration is not the same as the original one - you removed AllowOverride from Directory directive, and that means you won't be able to use .htaccess file in C:\Program Files\Zend\ZendServer\GUI\html directory. Directory options setup are different from URL options setup, that's why they used both of them.

Comment: Long writeup in the apache docs about Directory vs. Location (and others): http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/sections.html

Answer (score 2):

Location can be used when using an AJP or proxy redirect.  For example, Oracle's PLSQL APEX module uses the following URL:  /pls/apex/f?p=1:1

If you try to restrict this using directory, it will never work since it's a pass-thru and not a physical directory on the server.  Location works!