# webdav, controlling access via group of users

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, apache-2.4, webdav

I'm in the first steps with webdav.

To restrict access to a folder it's possible to use:

```
Require user myownuser
```

Is it possible to allow access to a group of users (like samba does)?

Comment: Since you've got access to the complete apache auth for this, **yes**.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using Apache httpd 2.4 as your webdav server.

In that case, you can use the `mod_authz_dbm` [module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_dbm.html) or the `mod_authnz_ldap` [module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html) to provide user and group information to Apache and use this in your `<Directory>` statement for access control.

Something like this (untested and copied from the docs):

```
<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/foo">
    Require all granted
    Dav On

    AuthType Basic
    AuthName DAV
    AuthBasicProvider dbm
    AuthDBMUserFile "site/data/users"
    AuthDBMGroupFile "site/data/users"
    Require dbm-group admin


</Directory>
```

Comment: May I ask your opinion on this https://superuser.com/questions/1194753/webdav-directory-vs-location also?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/196957/difference-between-location-and-directory-apache-directives

Comment: In this case, `<Directory>` is the way to go, as you want to protect the content of the directory regardless of the URL which is used to access it.

Comment: Another one, https://superuser.com/questions/1194676/webdav-linking-to-a-folder-in-users-home, please.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `mod_authz_dbm` and `mod_authnz_ldap`, I'm going with `mod_authz_groupfile`. Curious about the possible disadvantages of this in relation to the others?

```
 Alias /webdav/tmp /var/www/webdav/tmp
 <Location /webdav/tmp>
     DAV On
     AuthType Digest
     AuthName "webdav"
     AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/users.password
     AuthGroupFile /etc/apache2/groups
     Require group mygorup
 </Location>
```